# I would like to have contact information for the inventor

Tags: patent-infringement, infringement

Craig 623-552-8216              I have been ripped off by an attorney that claimed he was going to partner up with me. He disappeared over night from Chandler Az. Apparently moving to California and filing  U S provisional patent application.  And now his name is on the patent I took to his office and I haven't reviewed any money or recognition . I do not understand how he can do this and get away with it . 
i have a contract from the first IP lawyer I went to see. thjs firm was very interested in my invention and ran a patent search and they offered me in writing a contract for my invention. They would do everything  I would get 15 percent yet would have no say so or voting rights concerning  my invention.  I took the contract they offered and said I would think about it..    I met with
david george schellenberg the following day another patent attorney and he too was very interested in my invention and told me not to sign the contract I had showed him that the other patent attorney offered me the day before. there trying steal your purse and blow smoke up dress at the same time he said you can make lot more than 15 percent they are offering   m here sure don't get ripped off

Question: Is there any basis upon which the PPA (provisional patent) be denied?

Comment: I wrote this question on my cell phone and this is why there are so many mistakes  in my writing . Please do the best you can to read my question . I need someone to help me with this.

Comment: you need a lawyer, not us.

Comment: You can edit your original question to make it more clear what you are asking.

Comment: How do you know they filed a provisional application? Did they tell you?

Comment: @CnotesArtistsArtist how has this one ended up?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question, you had an invention and showed it to two different patent attorneys who each offered to patent it and take it to market and give you 15%  percent or more of the profits. **Patent attorney do not offer to take over peoples' inventions and pay them a royalty.** It is against the code of ethics and, no matter how significant an invention was, no informed and honest person would make such an offer after a short meeting and a quick search. Some "invention promotion" companies do that sort of thing. They have generally no interest in the invention, just your payment for them to get started on the project.

I do not think either person was an actual patent attorney. The person you named does not show up on the [roster of patent attorneys](https://oedci.uspto.gov/OEDCI/practitionerSearchEntry) at the USPTO. For what it is worth, someone of that name is listed as one of the co-inventors on [Method for tinting a cartridge of caulking material 
US 7527421](https://www.google.com/patents/US7527421?dq=20090179050).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the patent application must state the name of the inventor and if necessary assign the IP rights  If the attorney is not an inventor, then (technically) the USPTO would need deny the patent on the basis that the attorney is not the inventor.  That being said, this would raise the question how would the USPTO know that the attorney is not the inventor?

Comment: I can prove that I brought a piece of paper that lists the closest invention the 3 day  patent search found